# Concatenation variable in React Native

Tags: reactjs, react-native

With React Native and API, I have `forum.color.slug` variable that is "blue".

`/global.js :`

```
global.bg_blue = '#3cb44b';
global.bg_text_blue = '#fff';
global.border_blue = '#3cb44b';
```

`/Components/Forum/ForumIndex.js :`

```
...
import '../../global.js'

...
<Text style={{color: 'bg_' + forum.color.slug }}/>
```

But it does not work, I think that the concatenation of the variable `'bg_' + forum.color.slug` does not work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried:

```js
`bg_${forum.color.slug}`
```